# How do I delete all the files that contain a certain string in a directory in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I found several examples that work as long as there are no spaces in the filenames.  Unfortunately, I have spaces in my filenames (not my choice, in fact they are the ones I need to remove).

So, for example, this is what I thought would work:

find . -type f | grep ).MOV | xargs rm

because I want to delete the files like:

- L112 (1).MOV
- L113 (1).MOV
- L113 (2).MOV
- etc.

and I want to keep the files like

- L112.MOV
- L113.MOV
- L114.MOV
- etc.

This finds the files correctly:

find . -type f | grep ).MOV

but when I pipe it to rm, the spaces in the filename screw it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rm *\).MOV
```

Comment: D'oh!  Yeah, that's probably better than using find :-).

Comment: The OP tried to make it confusing for us :)

Comment: Thank you, I was surprised that I couldn't find this answer with Google.  So simple.

Answer (score 4):

Tell `xargs` to use newlines as delimiters:

```
find . -type f | grep ).MOV | xargs -d'\n' rm
```

Better, have `find` do the matching and use `-print0` and `xargs -0` to allow *any* character in the file names, even `\n`!

```
find . -type f -name '*).MOV' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Even better, just have `find` call `rm` directly.

```
find . -type f -name '*).MOV' -exec rm {} +
```

Best, skip `rm` and have `find` do the deleting.

```
find . -type f -name '*).MOV' -delete
```

Or in this specific case, who needs all the heavy machinery?

```
rm *\).MOV
```

Comment: based on the way the question was asked this seems like the appropriate answer "how do I delete files that contain a string" -- should read "filename"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name "*).MOV" -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Many unix tools are fragile (or at least tricky to use correctly) in the presence of file names containing spaces and tabs, or even worse, newlines, so when you have a choice, you should avoid these characters in file names.

However, if you want to remove all files in the current directory (and all subdirectories) with a space in the name, the following will work.

```
find . -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

The `-print0` option tells find to use the NUL byte (\0) as the separator between file names instead of NL (\n).  Conversely, `-0` tells xargs to use NUL as the line separator instead of NL.  Alter the pattern argument to the `-name` option as needed to match the files you want to remove.

It can be a bit tricky to prevent `find` from recursing into subdirectories (although check out the `-maxdepth` argument), so if you only want to affect files in the current directory you might want to approach the problem differently.

Overall, I strongly recommend becoming fluent with `find` and `xargs`.  Individually, and especially when chained together as shown above, they make an extremely flexible toolkit for bulk file operations.

Answer (score 0):

In most Unix installations you can denote a space in a filename by prefixing it with a backslash.  So for instance, try this out:

```
mkdir blah
cd blah
touch file1
touch file2
touch "file 3"
touch "file 4"
```

Do an "ls" and you should see this:

file 3 file 4  file1   file2

Now do "ls *\ *" and you should see everything with a space in it:

file 3 file 4

So maybe just an "rm *\ *" is all you need? Or modify that regular expression slightly to fit your needs.

Hope that helps!